# setting the z-index top

Tags: html, css

I have a 'down' button on the right side of my website, that scrolls smoothly to the below fold area. But in smaller windows; netbooks, ipads etc - the button is pushed behind the content. How could I properly set the z-index of that image/div so when view on a smaller screen it appears above the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the z-index the more the div / img is in front of the rest. If you want to be sure that your button is in front of the rest use 9999.

Answer (score 2):

The z-index would have to be higher than the z-index of the DOM Object you want behind it.  In addition, the poistion would need to be set as relative (position:relative;).  By default, all DOM Objects have a z-index of 0.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments are correct, your button needs to have a higher z-index than the other content. Below is an example.

```
<body>
   <style type="text/css>
      .content
      {
         position:relative;
         z-index:1;
      }
      .button
      {
         position:relative;
         z-index:10;
      }
   </style>
   <div class="content">
      Content
   </div>
   <a class="button">
      Button
   </a>
</body>
```